# How to convert a polar plot in surface Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to display PolarPlot in the form of surface plot. I don't know how to achieve this task. 
for example I have chossen a very simple problem

```
                     a=4;
                     PolarPlot[Cos[x*a],{x,0,Pi}]
```

which returns the above pattern. I want to display the same pattern in Surface Plot form.
    [image]
for reference please see the below Pic
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [`PolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolarPlot.html) for your given function is actually

```
a = 2;
PolarPlot[Cos[x*a], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

The `PolarPlot` that you show corresponds to

```
a = 4;
PolarPlot[Sin[x*a], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

To display radius as a function of angle on a cartesian [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)

```
Plot[Abs[Sin[x*a]], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

Or as a [`LogPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogPlot.html)

[image]

The far-field radiation patterns that you show are not related to your function or your `PolarPlot`

**EDIT:** Using [`RegionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
RegionPlot[
 -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= Sin[a*ArcTan[y/x]] <=
  Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** Using [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html)

```
DensityPlot[Sin[a*ArcTan[y/x]],
 {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f},
   -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= f || f >= Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]],
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Then I want to know how the polar pattern actually appears in Density plot. Which function is used.

Comment: Recommend that you edit your question to clarify what function you are working with and what output you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Bob Hanlon , I want to know only whether it is possible to achieve the same pattern (as that of Polar) in Density Plot.